# how can I convert java.lang.String to kotlin.String? when click "convert java file to kotlin file"

Tags: java, string, kotlin

when click  "convert java file to kotlin" ,I found the type "java.lang.String" convert to "kotlin.String".But it maybe null,and throws Exception : "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null".

for example:
My java code:

```
public void test(String arg) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(arg)) {
        Log.d("test", arg);
    }
}
```

After convert java file to kotlin file:

```
fun test(arg: String) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(arg)) {
        Log.d("test", arg)
    }
}
```

My expected Type for the parmeter “arg” is "String?" instead of "String".

Although I realized that was very difficult for converter to figure out if types should be nullable or not, I still wondered if there is any way to configure this behavior.Force convert "java.lang.String" to "kotlin.String?".

Comment: Can you share the code ?

Comment: @azro  Yes, I have added my code in the question.

Comment: Add the ? yourself.

Comment: I've added a bit of info below, but if you expect the converter to be smart enough to figure out if types should be nullable or not, well, sometimes you might be lucky.

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between `String` in Java and `String` in Kotlin. The difference might not be so obvious, but:

- `String` in Java means: all Strings, including `null`.
- `String` in Kotlin means: all Strings, *excluding* `null`

You're trying to assign a null value to a Kotlin String, which you have defined as non-nullable (because you only defined it as `String`). If you want it to also accept null values, you need to change the type from `String` to `String?`, so, including a question mark. This tells Kotlin that the String can also be null.